# Make a multi request by JSON with facebook API

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to send 2 messsages in one POST request with facebook API .This is my JSON message data

```js
var messageData = [{
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      text: "a"
    }
  },
  {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      text: "b"
    }
  }];
```

I can send one message , but when i change messageData to an array of message, it can not send.
So can we do other ways with an Request for 2 messages.I am using Facebook Messenger Plaform

Comment: What does it say in the manual for the API? Just like everything else it needs to meet their criteria. Can't arbitrarily send array if manual says send object

Comment: So i need to make 2 requests ?

Comment: Do we have only this way to do it ??

Comment: Unless api docs tell you how to send multiples. What do the docs say? You are expected to at least read the documentation before asking questions here

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send multiple messages with one request. You have to use multiple requests.

See [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference).